# Is it possible to control the path for the Cancel button on react-admin's delete confirmation for `undoable={false}` setting?

Tags: react-admin

We have turned off optimistic rendering for deletion using `undoable={false}` in our lists

```
<List title="Patient List">
  <Datagrid rowClick="show">
    <TextField label="Patient ID" source="patientID" />
    <FunctionField label="Name" source="name" render={renderName()} />
    <EditButton />
    <DeleteButton undoable={false} />
  </Datagrid>
</List>
```

Works as described, except that in this spot, the `Cancel` button takes the user to the individual record page (e.g. '/patient/1234567890/show'). This makes sense for `<Edit title={'Edit Patient Information'} undoable={false} {...props}>` because clicking cancel stays on the edit form. But it is not ideal for a delete button in a list (which I imagine probably means the intended use case for `undoable={false}` is not in a list). I am aware I could remove the `<DeleteButton undoable={false} />` from the list altogether and do the following with bulk actions, which will provide similar functionality

```
const PostBulkActionButtons = props => (
  <Fragment>
    <BulkDeleteButton {...props} undoable={false} />
  </Fragment>
)

<List title="Patient List" bulkActionButtons={<PostBulkActionButtons />}>
  <Datagrid rowClick="show">
    ...
  </Datagrid>
</List>
```

But the client is married to the idea of a delete button for each record in the list. Is there a way for me to control the path of the Cancel button in the confirmation dialog that renders when `undoable={false}` or will I need to build my own confirmation dialog? Thanks!

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3359